# Angular 2 Material - Sidenav and Toolbar buttons are highlighed automatically

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm developing an Angular 2 app using *material2* library but there are some UI problems with buttons (md-button) in Toolbar and Sidenav.

When the sidenav is opened and the user move the cursor on one of buttons the first button is always highlighted automatically.

Moreover, when the sidenav is closed the menu button on the toolbar is highlighted automatically until the user click somewhere else.

Here is my layout:

```
<md-sidenav-container fullscreen>
<md-sidenav #sidenav mode="over"> <!-- mode="over/side/push" --> <!-- (open)="" -->
    <button md-button class="sidenav-link" [routerLink]="['/home']" (click)="sidenav.close()">HOME</button>
    <button md-button class="sidenav-link" [routerLink]="['/about']" (click)="sidenav.close()">ABOUT</button>
</md-sidenav>

<md-toolbar>
    <button md-button class="toolbar-menu-button" (click)="sidenav.toggle()"><i class="material-icons md-dark">menu</i></button>
    <span class="toolbar-spacer"></span>
    <button md-button class="toolbar-link" [routerLink]="['/home']" [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">HOME</button>
    <button md-button class="toolbar-link" [routerLink]="['/about']" [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">ABOUT</button>
    <span class="toolbar-spacer"></span>
</md-toolbar>

<div class="page-content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

And here is a pluker which shows the issue -> https://plnkr.co/edit/ve5Ez0WSinNyowxI46LO?p=preview

Comment: Hi @Androidian Did you ever figure this out? I am having the same woes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `cdk-focus-region-start` attribute on the selected item.

For example a very ugly minimal example:

```
<a #rla="routerLinkActive" [attr.cdk-focus-region-start]="rla.isActive ? '' : null">Home</a>
```

And the full blown link:

```
<a md-list-item 
   [routerLink]="['/home']" 
   #rla="routerLinkActive" 
   [attr.cdk-focus-region-start]="rla.isActive ? '' : null" 
   [routerLinkActive]="['active']"
   [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">Home</a>
```

This will set focus to the currently selected item when you open the menu instead of the top.

Information is scant but found this [on github](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/3265)

Edited:

Use `cdk-focus-region-start` as `cdk-focus-start` is depreciated. The code above has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

i tried another solution and it worked.
as far as i understand `routerLinkActive` allows to set arbitrary class for active anchor tag so i just added:

```
<mat-sidenav>
  <mat-nav-list>
    <a mat-list-item cdk-focus-region-start routerLinkActive="mat-list-item-focus" routerLink="/profile">
        ...
    </a>
  </mat-nav-list>
</mat-sidenav>
```

hope this'll help